# How to communicate my upcoming resignation to my employer?

Tags: professionalism, job-change, resignation

I work for a software consulting company. I have been with my current company for almost 5 years. I have been on the bench for 4 months. Bench means that I am not on a project but still getting paid full salary. Being on the bench also means that my employer can lay me off any day without giving me any advance notice.

After month 3 I was actively looking for a job. My employer on weekly basis tell me that they are currently looking for a project for me and they wanted to make sure that I am not looking anywhere else. I told them no I am not looking even though I had several interviews with several companies.

Now, with my current company I am on a project. The project is not really what I want to be doing but it is better than nothing. At the same time there is a really good opportunity with another employer which I interviewed for and I am 99% sure that I will get the job.

When and if I resign how will I convey that to my current employer? I am sure they are going to ask me that why did you not tell us before and now what are we going to tell the client?

Comment: You've been paid for doing nothing for four months?

Comment: What compels you to provide a reason for leaving beyond "I've accepted a new opportunity. Here's my 2 weeks' notice."?

Comment: @KatieK The only reason is that my current company asked me that if I am looking for a job outside and I said NO so they gave me a new project which I am currently on. I don't necessarily enjoy this project since the technologies used does not intrigue me but after 4 months on bench you have no choice.

Comment: @amphibient Most consulting has the premise of the paid "bench" where you are paid, at least partially, while waiting for the next project.  Usually you get saddled with internal backfill projects to work on while on the bench, so it's not something most developers want to be doing.

Comment: You lied; You can either tell the truth now or continue to lie.  Don't do anything until you actually sign that job offer.

Answer (score 12):

How do you announce your resignation? The way anyone would.

You write a letter containing words like these: "My last day with the company will be (such-and-such a day). I will be happy to do whatever is necessary to introduce my successor to my work on the (XYZ) project, and provide a smooth transition. I am grateful for the opportunity to work with you and with such an excellent team."

I suggest you arrange a start date with the new company two weeks after your announced last day with the old company. This gives you the flexibility to negotiate with the old company if they want you to stay a week or two longer.  If they don't want you to do that, you can either take some time off or ask the new company if you can start earlier.

It was kind of them to keep you on staff while they looked for work for you. However: It's not "being on the bench" that gives your employer the right to let you go without notice at any time, it's your terms of employment. They could do that anytime they want, and so can you.

Don't become too worried about the idea that being on the bench somehow makes you indebted to this company. It doesn't. Successful consulting businesses build in the cost of making sure good employees are available for projects.

Comment: Thanks! I left my current company 2 years ago and rejoined them back 1 year ago. For some being on the bench without a project for 4 months is great but for me I want to learn. Also my current project is not of my interest and my passion is somewhere else. I am not sure if this will be the right move or not but I don't want to miss this chance and complain about my current company for the rest of my life!!

Answer (score 5):

> When and if I resign how will I convey that to my current employer? I
>   am sure they are going to ask me that why did you not tell us before
>   and now what are we going to tell the client?

Do not resign until you have a job offer. Even if you are telling yourself "I am 99% sure that I will get the job", *do not resign* until you have the offer in writing and have communicated your acceptance of it.

Will your current employer be upset that you are leaving? Maybe! That's always a possibility. An employee's resignation can be a massive pain in the ass. *But that's business.* People leave for better opportunities. Every company has to deal with this.

And if they ask "why did you not tell us before?" That's an easy question! Because you hadn't made the decision to resign and accept another job offer before! As soon as that decision was made, you handed in your resignation!

Comment: Yep, you never notify an employer you're on your way out the door until it's official and all papers are in order. (They do the exact same to their employees, they don't tell you you're about to be laid off until they hand you a slip of paper and walk you out the door) Employers have to plan to lose people. It happens all the time. Some take other jobs, others retire, and regretfully people do die without warning. It's life and it's business.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment makes a lot of sense and you are right, it is business :)